# How to get sequences for each row with different name in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

The problem: I need to get values for X column with select statement, example:

People | X

--------------

name1  | 1

name1  | 2

name1  | 3

name2  | 1

name2  | 2

name3  | 1

....

where people is unlimited count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
  people,
  row_number() over(partition by people) as x
from yourtable
```

**Update: Small feedback as summary of comments:**
As Dave Costa and APC say, the results are non-deterministic. That is, if you run this query tomorow it is possible that first name1 to get id 2 in some conditions. However the query will still be correct.
If your table have attributes like DateInserted, DateOfBirth or other that can make a difference between same names, you can improve the query for example like this:

```
select 
  people,
  row_number() over(partition by people order by DateOfBirth) as x
from yourtable
```

Comment: Just want to add a note that as written the results are non-deterministic, i.e. within each name there is no guarantee that the same rows would get assigned 1,2,3 from one execution to the next.  To make it deterministic, add an `ORDER BY` clause to the analytic window; the question doesn't contain enough information to suggest an appropriate ordering.

Comment: Yes, Thank You Dave Costa too, i edited code with order by people after partition by people but until Florin Ghita willn't accept this code change, nobody can see this improved code...

Comment: @user963601 - I have voted to reject your edit.  Ordering by PEOPLE won't make any difference, because that clause specifies the sort order *within the partition*.  As the partition is PEOPLE the query would still be non-deterministic.  What you need is a sort order which makes sense as a way of prioritising records for the same value of PEOPLE.  A column such as DATE_CREATED would fit the bill, so that the records are order by earliest or most recent first.

Comment: if order by people isn't included, then: ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification
30485. 00000 -  "missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification"
*Cause:    Either the ORDER BY expression is mandatory for this function, or
           there is an aggregation group without any ORDER by expression.

Comment: @user963601 I've put a summary of comments in the answer.

Comment: @user963601 what version of Oracle you run?

Comment: you shoudn't get that error. Are you basicaly use the same query like in the answer?

Comment: If you can order, sure is better.